# How to Split string in f# without taking out the caracter used to split

Tags: string, types, f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to take a string like `"hello world : bye world"` and get `["hello world"; ":" ;"bye world"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest function I can think of to pass your test case.

```
let split (str:string) =
    str.Split ':'
    |> Seq.collect(fun x -> [":"; x.Trim()])
    |> Seq.tail
    |> Seq.toList

split "hello world : bye world" // ["hello world"; ":"; "bye world"]
```